# Draw a stratified sample in panel data

Tags: sampling, panel-data, stratification, representative

**Question:** How can we draw a stratified sample in panel data context when the stratifying variables are not fixed over time?

**Background:** I have panel data on workers (id) over time (t). I want to draw a X% sample from the population and make sure that this is stratified by sector and region with proportions as in the main population. However, workers change sector and region over time. So if just draw a stratified sample in period t=0 it will have the right proportions then but change over time as workers switch. Also, if I just draw from all periods then I can not make sure that all time observations per id are covered.

Comment: Consider time-stratified sampling. It's a variation of stratified sampling in which time becomes a stratifying variable.

Comment: How does that work or can you suggest a reference? Because, in principle, I want the keep at periods for an id that is drawn.